# How do I hide a particular user from the login screen?

Tags: lightdm, unity-greeter

How do I hide a particular user from the login screen on a default install of 11.10 and higher? (ie. using Unity Greeter)?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

If your system uses `AccountsService`, you **can not** hide a user from the greeter screen by reconfiguring `lightdm` because it defers to `AccountsService`.  That is stated very clearly in the comments in `/etc/lightdm/users.conf`.

---

**What you need to do** instead is to reconfigure `AccountsService`.

To hide a user named `XXX`, create a file named

```
/var/lib/AccountsService/users/XXX
```

containing two lines:

```
[User]
SystemAccount=true
```

If the file already exists, make sure you append the `SystemAccount=true` line to the `[User]` section.

The change takes effect after reloading AccountsService:

```
sudo systemctl restart accounts-daemon.service
```

Comment: works on vanilla 14.04 setup

Comment: Tested working on Ubuntu 16.04 too.

Comment: This works also on Ubuntu 17.10 with Gnome 3

Comment: And is still the correct answer for Ubuntu 19.04 Disco Dingo.

Comment: This is working on Ubuntu 19.04. Remember to use XXX as the actual username, not the alias. For example, 'postgres' username has 'PostgreSQL' alias. In this case, you have to use 'postgres' as the name of the file.

Comment: As it's Ubuntu based, this also works in Elementary OS 5.1.

Comment: Also works on vanilla Ubuntu 20.04. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to hide all users without having to create a separate file for each user under /var/lib/AccountsService/users?

Comment: Btw, there is a standard lib [`crudini`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/crudini.1.html), which allows you to do so in scripting (less painful, more stable than `sed` or a blind `>>` append): `crudini --set /var/lib/AccountsService/users/$_user User SystemAccount "true"`

Comment: You can run `# systemctl restart accounts-daemon.service` to apply the change immediately.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 23.10

Answer (score 45):

**Currently this method is not working because of a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/857651) in lightdm.**

**Please check the bug status before applying this method.**

---

Heres what you want to do:

First, make a backup of your config.

```
sudo cp /etc/lightdm/users.conf /etc/lightdm/users.conf.bak
```

Then, you need to edit your config:

```
sudo nano /etc/lightdm/users.conf
```

You'll see something like this:

```sh
#
# User accounts configuration
#
# NOTE: If you have AccountsService installed on your system, then LightDM will
# use this instead and these settings will be ignored
#
# minimum-uid = Minimum UID required to be shown in greeter
# hidden-users = Users that are not shown to the user
# hidden-shells = Shells that indicate a user cannot login
#
[UserAccounts]
minimum-uid=500
hidden-users=nobody nobody4 noaccess
hidden-shells=/bin/false /usr/sbin/nologin
```

Of interest to us is the part here:

`hidden-users=nobody nobody4 noaccess`

To hide the username `james`, just add it like this:

`hidden-users=nobody nobody4 noaccess james`

Then, reboot your computer and it should be gone.

As a reference to others, see

See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/accountsservice/+bug/857651

On some versions of lighdm (Ubuntu 14.04) you need to rename `[UserAccounts]` to `[UserList]` (in `/etc/lightdm/users.conf`) for this method to work. *(If you're interested in why this may be necessary, see `common/user-list.c:321` from lightdm source.)*

Comment: Does not work on 14.04 anymore but answer http://askubuntu.com/a/575390/7304 from @marc-culler below works.

Comment: Still not fixed after six years, sigh :(

Comment: @Bulletmagnet well Ubuntu isn't using lightdm anymore :(

Comment: Whatever it's using, the problem persists :(

Comment: It worked for me on Gentoo till these days when I installed AccountsService. Now the accepted answer work for me.

Comment: not useful on Ubuntu 23.10

Answer (score 17):

Your option until [bug 857651](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/857651) is fixed is to create the user with uid < 1000

For example, to assign new uid less than 1000, (we are using 999) use this command

```
sudo usermod -u 999 user-name
```

Replace the `user-name` with the actual user name, just as `anwar` or `detly` etc.

Comment: This hides the user, but if you're changing the uid you may also want to change the gid, since they are usually the same number: `sudo groupmod -g999 user-name`. And as dqvn2002 mentions in their answer, for Ubuntu 12.04 you'll need a number < 500, so 999 won't work.

Comment: And don't forget! When you change the user id, any private files owned by that user will suddenly become inaccessible. You'll need to run (e.g.) `sudo chown -R user-name:user-name /home/user-name`.

Comment: On ubuntu 20.04, and landed here because an intended system account with uid/gid 998/996 at creation got added to the login screen. AccountsService actually also seems to explicitely opts out (with the accepted answer) user gdm with uid/gid 125/130 . TBH I had the same view than you, but it is not (anymore?) working at least on Ubuntu 20.04. Probable explanation is that `/etc/lightdm/users.conf` got actually set with `minimum-uid=500`.

Comment: `cat /etc/passwd|grep 999` can check if the user id isn't taken (i'm not sure if it matters, and yes it can show user names that contain the id so it's not perfect)

Answer (score 10):

because the Ubuntu 12.04 setup

```
[UserAccounts]  
minimum-uid=500
```

so we need to reduce the `uid` less than 500

example: `sudo usermod -u 499 user-name`

It works with me! SOLVED
Good luck.

Comment: You may want/need to also change the group id, and `chown` any files owned by the user, as I commented on OerHeks' answer.

Answer (score 4):

This method is not works on Ubuntu 13.10.

To hide user login names correctly You must to open LightDM config:

```
sudo vim /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

and add the following options:

```
greeter-hide-users=true
greeter-show-manual-login=true
```

Then save and reboot. That's all.

Comment: The accepted method is still not working on 14.04 and showing the manual login seems to me the best option too. In 14.04 add the lines listed in this answer to /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-ubuntu.conf .. if you want also to disable the guest user then append allow-guest=false

Answer (score 1):

This a variation of James' answer. You can hide users in lightDM by simply assigning them an ID below the minimum ID found in:

```
/etc/lightdm/users.conf
```

On my PC it was 1000

```
# minimum-uid = Minimum UID required to be shown in greeter
# hidden-users = Users that are not shown to the user
# hidden-shells = Shells that indicate a user cannot login
#
[UserAccounts]
minimum-uid=1000
```

You can change UID easilly in terminal:

```
sudo usermod -u PutUserNameHere
```

It works on my PC (in 2016), so I guess the lightDM bug that Eliah Kagan mentioned in 2014 with regards James' answer has been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu:

```
printf "[User]\nSystemAccount=true\n" | sudo tee /var/lib/AccountsService/users/libvirt-qemu
sudo systemctl restart accounts-daemon.service
```

Answer (score 0):

I just got this done using Login Manager Settings, a nice little graphical app which can be installed in a matter of seconds with flatpak:

```
flatpak install https://dl.flathub.org/repo/appstream/io.github.realmazharhussain.GdmSettings.flatpakref
```

Ok, it doesn't support hiding specific users (it will just hide all of them requiring everyone to type their username) but honestly I don't even think about complaining considering how quick and comfortable the process was.

That said, the same article where I found about the above app, also describes [two other more conventional approaches](https://fostips.com/hide-user-list-gdm-login-screen-ubuntu-20-04-20-10/), which are reported to work fine with latest Ubuntu releases (the article is just one month old).

- Option 1: Create configuration file to disable user list
- Option 2: Disable user list via settings command

Read more about them at https://fostips.com/hide-user-list-gdm-login-screen-ubuntu-20-04-20-10/