# How to hide users from the user account list of the login screen in Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: login-screen, 12.10, username

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I hide a particular user from the LightDM login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92349/how-do-i-hide-a-particular-user-from-the-lightdm-login-screen)

I want to hide users from login screen. I have tried to modify a file in `/etc/gdm`, but that folder doesn't exist in my file system. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu uses lightdm instead of gdm by default now, so you need to edit lightdm's configuration. Here's the default `/etc/lightdm/users.conf`:

```
#
# User accounts configuration
#
# NOTE: If you have AccountsService installed on your system, then LightDM will
# use this instead and these settings will be ignored
#
# minimum-uid = Minimum UID required to be shown in greeter
# hidden-users = Users that are not shown to the user
# hidden-shells = Shells that indicate a user cannot login
#
[UserAccounts]
minimum-uid=500
hidden-users=nobody nobody4 noaccess
hidden-shells=/bin/false /usr/sbin/nologin
```

Append the users you want hidden to the `hidden-users=`-line there.