# Hide an account from the login screen

Tags: login-screen

I am using Ubuntu 12.10, can someone give-me instructions on how to make an account invisible from the login screen without deleting it?

Comment: This might be a dublicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/92349/how-do-i-hide-a-particular-user-from-the-lightdm-login-screen

Answer (score 3):

Edit `/etc/lightdm/users.conf`, add the user to the `hidden-users` setting.