# Hide user accounts

Tags: users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I hide a particular user from the LightDM login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92349/how-do-i-hide-a-particular-user-from-the-lightdm-login-screen)

Is there away to hide specific user accounts from the login screen and the drop down menu on the desktop menu, I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 (precise)

Comment: Hello, and welcome to AskUbuntu! Please make a search for your question before posting, there's a good chance your question has already been answered! ----^ See above comment. :)