# How to not show a user in the Ubuntu login screen?

Tags: display, users, login-screen

I have created a user called **training** using the adduser command and user **training** appears in the login screen. How to not show any particular user in the login screen? I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with the default Unity.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How do I hide a particular user from the LightDM login screen?](http://askubuntu.com/q/92349/52726).

Comment: Tried it out and doesn't work.

Comment: Editing the `users.conf` file? How about giving the user a UID less than 500? Try `sudo usermod -u 499 training`. Check that it changed by `grep training /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f3`, which should output 499.

Comment: changing the UID for the user worked