# Remove postgresql and daemon user entries in Ubuntu Logon Screen

Tags: users, login-screen, postgresql

I installed ubuntu 13.10 and installed some software. Now I see two new users in the logon screen called `daemon` and `postgres`. How can this happen? Is there a way to remove these entries from logon screen without removing these two user roles (I think these two roles are essential for certain applications).

Answer (score 2):

indeed they're essential for certain services but if you just want to hide them, edit `/etc/lightdm/users.conf` file (the line that says `hidden-users =`) and append those users which you don't want to be shown.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did it, but still problem persists :/

Comment: did you remove the `#` character. for example here's what it should be: `hidden-users = user1 user2 user3`

Comment: That line was not commented @V1R4N64R

Comment: i do remember a bug in lightdm which you couldn't hide the user from login screen. don't know if that was patched later or not. [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/accountsservice/+bug/857651)'s the reference to that. but go ahead and search for that. here's a topic about this: [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/92349/how-do-i-hide-a-particular-user-from-the-lightdm-login-screen).