# How to hide a particular account in the login screen?

Tags: login, login-screen

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit. I have two(2) accounts.

- **admin01** is for administrator, Account type is Administrator. and the other,
- **user01** is for computer user, Account type is Standard.

I want to see only **user01** in the login screen. And I want to access **admin01** by typing the username and password.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Add the desired user under `hidden-users` in file `/etc/lightdm/users.conf`. Open it with `sudo -H gedit /etc/lightdm/users.conf`

For manual login you will need line `greeter-show-manual-login=false` in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` file. You can open it with `sudo -H gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`

[image]
[image]

**Update**

So, turns out the accepted method doesn't work in Ubuntu 14.04, however [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/575390/295286) right here seems to work. Edit a file for user you want to hide in `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/`, specifically line `SystemAccount=true`. Restart lightdm with `sudo service lightdm restart`

Comment: Note , you dont need # before greeter-show-manual-login=true  . In my file it's commented-out

Comment: Cannot disappear the **admin01**. There's **admin01**, **user01** and **Login** in login screen. How can I do only **user01** appear in the login screen?

Comment: Updated my answer, take a loot