# How to hide / remove "postgres" user in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: users, postgresql, user-management

I recently installed `postgresql`. (I know very little about it, but may try it out at some point.) I noticed that a user named `postgres` (which I do not recall creating manually) is now listed both on the login screen and in the session menu. Neither the `users` not the `groups` commands list `postgres` or anything like that.

Can I remove that user and give the necessary permission to my primary user account instead (without rendering the package unusable)? Otherwise, can I at least hide it from the login screen and session menu instead? Either way, how do I do it?

Comment: Which loginscreen are you using? If you don't know, do this command: `cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager`.

Comment: It says `/usr/sbin/lightdm`. Which may have also changed recently, because I installed a package for Gnome "fallback" or "classic" or whatever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hide a specific user by creating a file in `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/` named with the username, in this case: `postgres`.

```
$ sudo vim /var/lib/AccountsService/users/postgres
```

And add the following two lines:

```
[User]
SystemAccount=true
```

If it happens that your system dosen't use `AccountsService` then hide the user by editing the `/etc/lightdm/users.conf` file and add the username to this line:

```
hidden-users=nobody nobody4 noaccess postgres
```

Then restart `lightdm` (this will restart the current session so be sure to save your work):

```
$ sudo service lightdm restart
```

Comment: If I don't comment here again soon, then editing `/etc/lightdm/users.conf` did the trick... thanks!

Comment: @BrianZ You're welome! I'm glad it worked.

Comment: Actually, once I finally had the chance to restart, I saw that it didn't work. Any further suggestions?

Comment: [This related question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/92349/how-do-i-hide-a-particular-user-from-the-lightdm-login-screen) says there is [a known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/857651) in the `lightdm` package. So that must be why this answer did not work for me.