# Why do I have a "libvirt qemu" account in Lock/Switch account options in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, login, qemu

Is "libvirt qemu" provided by Ubuntu 16.04 officially, or did I do something wrong/right?

```
$ grep -E 'libvirt|qemu' /etc/passwd"
libvirt-qemu:x:64055:134:Libvirt Qemu,,,:/var/lib/libvirt:/bin/false
libvirt-dnsmasq:x:124:137:Libvirt Dnsmasq,,,:/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq:/bin/false
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and show the output of `grep -E 'libvirt|qemu' /etc/passwd` ?

Comment: what display manager (GDM, SDDM, etc) are you using?  it's probably a slight misconfiguration.  if `libvirt-qemu` is shown but `libvirt-dnsmasq` isn't, then the display manager isn't filtering out `/bin/false` shells but is filtering out system accounts.  `libvirt-qemu` has a high but normal-user UID.

Comment: To answer @quixotic question please [edit] the content of `/etc/X11/default-display-manager` into your post. thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Even if it was answered "correctly" I have no way of testing and honestly accepting an answer, because I reinstalled Ubuntu. @ElderGeek

Comment: Corresponding report in Ubuntu's bug tracker: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvirt/+bug/1674765

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have a configuration problem in the file `/etc/lightdm/users.conf` as users with the shell `/bin/false` as is the case with the libvirt-qemu should never show up in the account list for login or switch to. This is controlled by the the line `hidden-shells=/bin/false /usr/sbin/nologin` in the aforementioned `/etc/lightdm/users.conf` file.

*However*, if you have the package `accountsservice` installed, then that overrides any settings in `/etc/lightdm/users.conf`. If `accountsservice` doesn't hide an account with nologin/false shells, then it may be a bug as mentioned in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/940069/225694).

Sources:

[How do I hide a particular user from the login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92349/how-do-i-hide-a-particular-user-from-the-login-screen)

`/etc/lightdm/users.conf` on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS and 16.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 38):

The `accountsservice` package seems to have a bug, since it shows nologin-shell accounts.

As a workaround, simply use these two commands:

```
printf "[User]\nSystemAccount=true\n" | sudo tee /var/lib/AccountsService/users/libvirt-qemu
sudo systemctl restart accounts-daemon.service
```

Comment: This worked and is much simpler for Ubuntu 17.04.  The setup described by Elder Geek was already in place, but still had the issue.

Comment: This doesn't work for me on Debian 9 (Stretch). The directory and the daemon exist but after I created the file as described and rebooted the *libvirt-qemu* entry persists.

Comment: This gives me bash:` /var/lib/AccountsService/users/libvirt-qemu: Permission denied`, even on sudo.

Comment: @darksoulsong: It seems you tried to execute the file which is not permitted. Double-check that you correctly copied the command line or edit the file with an interactive editor like `nano /var/lib/AccountsService/users/libvirt-qemu`.

Comment: In Ubuntu 18.04 the libvirt-qemu user is still displayed on Lightdm's login screen and can be hidden with the instructions above.

Comment: I would suggest adding flag `-a` to `tee` command above to make sure that doesn't overwrite any existing configuration in that file. Other than that, nice workaround.

Comment: Works pretty well for me on Elementary OS 5

Answer (score 7):

***warning*** : *In case you work with libvirt I would advice against doing this, since it deletes the account and makes libvirt stop working*

I accidentally pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd> once trying out some shortcuts I had seen on a Website this took me to a Black Fullscreen **tty** session where I typed in  `chvt N` and `startx` to get out to GUI of Ubuntu but this failed and resulted in an additional account named "**Libvirt qemu**" above my present user name at the Login Page during reboot.

Anyone trying to figure out how to remove Libvirt qemu user, this is how I removed it :

1. Go to System Settings -> User Accounts
2. Unlock the UA control
3. Click on Libvirt qemu account
4. Remove Libvirt qemu by clicking the small  "**-**"  sign at bottom left side.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful and simple. I got the qemu account when I tried to install KVM for my android emulator's hardware acceleration.

Comment: This is ofcourse not very helpful if You work with libvirt. This deletes the account entirely from system and makes libvirt stop working.

Comment: @Sprinterfreak that is exactly why I described how I got the error so that people who didn't get it that way would not risk using my method to get rid of the additional account, I'll add a warning on top.

Answer (score 4):

For whatever reason the system user "libvirt-gemu" is created with the uid  64055 (at least in Ubuntu 16.04.2).

This is how 16.04.2 creates it:

```
libvirt-qemu:x:64055:130:Libvirt Qemu,,,:/var/lib/libvirt:/bin/false
libvirt-dnsmasq:x:121:129:Libvirt Dnsmasq,,,:/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq:/bin/false
```

And this is how it should be:

```
libvirt-qemu:x:125:130:Libvirt Qemu,,,:/var/lib/libvirt:/bin/false
libvirt-dnsmasq:x:121:129:Libvirt Dnsmasq,,,:/var/lib/libvirt/dnsmasq:/bin/false
```

To correct this simply change the uid of "libvirt-qemu" and it's belonging files. "Libvirt Qemu" will then disappear from the login!

Read e.g. [nixCraft - How to Change a USER and GROUP ID on Linux For All Owned Files](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-change-user-group-uid-gid-for-all-owned-files/) to know how to do this.

Comment: *"For whatever reason the system user "libvirt-gemu" is created with the uid 64055 ..."*. AFAICT, the adoption of 64055 for the `libvirt-qemu` UID and GID in Debian (and therefore in its derivative distros) was introduced in a patch to `libvirt-daemon-system`, filed in the Debian bug tracker on 14 Nov 2016 as [#844339](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=844339). Further explanation exists in [Debian bug report #843881](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=843881) and [Ubuntu bug report #1637601](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvirt/+bug/1637601).

Comment: Digging a little further into those bug reports, I see that the relevant Debian maintainer pre-allocated UID/GID 64055 to `libvirt-qemu` very slightly earlier: [11 Nov 2016](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=843881#10).

Comment: UID has to be below 1000 to not show up in the user manager. 125 was in my case (Ubuntu) still occupied by gdm, so find next free number.

Comment: Same with Ubuntu 18.04, also the users were still present even after `apt purge libvirt*`. So I had to delete them manually.

Comment: I reported a bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvirt/+bug/1903509 about incorrect behavior of packages accountsservice and libvirt-daemon-system combined. The workaround is to create file `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/libvirt-qemu`. See bug for details.

Answer (score 3):

At one point either you, or another application installed as a prerequisite, *qemu*.

Comment: I had this problem due to installing `gnome-boxes`.