# System user in login screen, Ubuntu 16.04 locks up

Tags: 16.04

Good evening, I was attempting to setup Virtualization on Ubuntu 16.04, and I restarted my computer. Now I have a normally hidden user, named "Libvirt Qemu" on my login screen. I cannot switch users, because it is highlighted by default, and it locks up when it reaches the login screen.

I want to reach my main user account Kaitlyn, but I can't when the system locks up on the login screen, when a key is pressed.

I do have access to a root terminal using recovery mode, so I'm guessing any fix will have to be done there. I have tried the all the methods shown [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/897026/why-do-i-have-a-libvirt-qemu-account-in-lock-switch-account-options-in-ubuntu) It didn't work, unfortunately.

Picture of my login screen:

[image: Picture of my login screen]

Thank you for reading, have a good day.
~ Kaitlyn

(Thank you Chai T Rex, I will do that now.) 
New development: after a ton of fiddling around with the passwd file and user accounts, I have gotten it it to highlight my user, however, it is still locked up. I tried the following:

- Removed the user altogether
  (This removed it from the login screen, it still locked up however.
- Deleted the "passwd" file from /etc/ (I backed it up of course.)
  This did what you'd expect, and rendered Ubuntu inoperable, so I used a live CD to bring back the backup.
  I am now trying to see if it's an issue with UID's.

(Edit 2) I have been working all day to figure this issue out, and I have finally given up. I wiped the hard drive and started with a fresh copy of Ubuntu, installed alongside Kali Linux.

If it helps, [here is the guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation) I followed to get this result

Comment: I backed up my passwd and group files and deleted the system user. It disappeared from the login screen but I still get the lockup.

Comment: You can click the edit link under your question to add that in.