# Login screen shows tomcat user

Tags: user-management

Is it normal that tomcat user created in tomcat setup to be seen in login screen? Is there a way to hide that from login screen?

Comment: The tomcat user should be a `system user` not a normal one. Please post the like to the installation steps

Comment: these are the steps I followed [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: It's a bug as answered below...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug. The tomcat user is a system account and not a user account. There is now way that it should be displayed on your login screen. I had a similar issue when I installed KVM. It listed "Libvirt Qemu" as a user on login screen. The issue was reported as a bug on launchpad:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvirt/+bug/1672112

If you get annoyed by a particular user appearing on your login screen. You can see the following post to hide a user from login/welcome screen

[How do I hide a particular user from the login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92349/how-do-i-hide-a-particular-user-from-the-login-screen)

Comment: Was able to hide the  tomcat user using the info available on thread. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I fixed mine on Ubuntu 16.04:

1. Change `UID` to a value lower than 1000 so user will be hidden by `lightdm`:

   ```
   sudo usermod -u 998 tomcat
   ```
2. Do same for `group id - GID`"

   ```
   sudo groupmod -g 998 tomcat
   ```
3. Since `tomcat` won't have access to the `/opt/tomcat` modify or reset ownership:

   ```
   sudo chgrp -R tomcat /opt/tomcat
   ```
4. Please note that in step `1` above terminal will display process id that used by `tomcat`. Kill them and start from `step 1`:

   ```
   sudo kill -9 <process_id>
   ```

Note:

You can get the tomcat process id's with:

```
ps -eLo pid,ppid,stat,euser | grep tomcat
```

And the new `UID` I used id purely random pick that which is ok by you.