# My user appears twice in the login screen

Tags: gnome, login, users

When i start my Ubuntu 18.04 system i get prompted to the login screen but my user appears twice in the login screen
the first instance accepts my usual password but the second instance doesnt
what does this mean? how can i remove the second instance?

to be more clear, i don't get TWO login screens, instead one login screen with my user duplicated in it.
thanks in advance.

I tried to look for the file at which the login entries was present, but didn't find it  and didn't find a bug like mine.

Comment: Do you perhaps have two different accounts configured with the same GECOS fullname (which is the field displayed in the GUI login box, iirc)? Something like `getent passwd | awk -F: '$3+0 > 500 {print $5}'` might help to confirm.

Comment: yeah thats right! how did that happen and how to fix it?

Comment: You should be able to do that using the `chfn` command - please see below

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if two user accounts have the same [GECOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecos_field#Format) *full name*.

You can check the usernames and GECOS records for all the (likely) non-system accounts using

```
getent passwd | awk -F: '$3+0 > 500 {print $1 ": " $5}'
```

If there's a duplicate in the fullnames (the first comma-separated field of the GECOS record), then you can change one or other (or both, if you prefer) using the `chfn` command e.g.

```
sudo chfn -f 'new name for userX' userX
```

If you don't even want to see an entry for one of the accounts, then you can hide it from the greeter altogether - see [How do I hide a particular user from the login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92349/how-do-i-hide-a-particular-user-from-the-login-screen)

Of course, if the account was created in error you can delete it - but be sure to back up any data just in case.