# Hide certain users from login screen greeter (Ubuntu 19.10)

Tags: login, users, login-screen

Hi I just finished installing Ubuntu 19.10 on my daughter's computer.
I want to hide my own account from the login greeter.
I found a way to hide the list of all accounts but that is not really what I want, because that way you need to type the username then and password and it is inconvenient.

Is there a way to only hide certain accounts from the greeter? While still retaining the feature of showing the remaining accounts (not all of them) and just click a user and only type the password?

I've found instructions for Ubuntu 18.04 but they didn't work in 19.10

Thank you

Josh

Comment: What `dm` were the instructions you find for 18.04?  If they were for a different display.manager, you could make 19.10 use the dm your instructions are intended for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even though Its a duplicate of [How do I hide a particular user from the login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/q/92349/739431)

I have just tried it whether its working or not in `Ubuntu 19.10` Fresh Install

It worked..

`sudo -H nautilus /var/lib/AccountsService/users/`

[image]

I have a, b, c, & d user accounts while bullet is my own account (Admin)

I would like to hide user a & c

[image]

[image]

so open file `a` and `c` and make SystemAccount field to true.

```
[User]
Icon=/var/lib/AccountsService/icons/a
SystemAccount=true
```

then logout and login

[image]

the same way I have hidden the Admin User also

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time, It works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

#### bash scriptable solution:

```
for _user in fred mike joe
do
    _guard crudini --set /var/lib/AccountsService/users/$_user User SystemAccount "true"
done
```

see [askubuntu.com/a/575390](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92349/how-do-i-hide-a-particular-user-from-the-login-screen/575390#575390)