# What does the "Not In List" button do in the Ubuntu login screen?

Tags: users, login-screen

In Ubuntu 21.04, what does the "Not In List" button do when you're trying to log in to your account?

Answer (score 3):

In principle, this list contains all of the Ubuntu users that can login, i.e. have a login shell specified in `/etc/passwd`.

However, a systems administrator can choose to hide a user from the list on the login page. On how to do this, see [How do I hide a particular user from the login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92349/how-do-i-hide-a-particular-user-from-the-login-screen)